# How to change what PHP version Apache uses?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, server

I'm trying to install PHP7 alongside PHP7.4 on my Ubuntu 20.04 server and make Apache use the former. Here's what I tried so far:

**Installed PHP 7.0**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.0
```

**Changed the defaults**

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

**Restarted Apache**

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

I even rebooted the machine a  couple times, but when I open the `phpinfo()` page on my browser, it still shows I'm on 7.4.24. Via CLI however it seems to work fine.

What step did I miss to make Apache use PHP7.0?

Comment: How did you execute `phpinfo()` ? Using your browser or in the command line?

Comment: @Cid Good question. Via console I can use PHP 7.0 just fine, it's only Apache that won't switch over for some reason. I also updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: You're probably missing `libapache2-mod-php7.0`.